# purecss.io and wrapping a LabelFor

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, yui-pure-css

I'm using purecss.io on a project of mine and I am having an issue when trying to apply a label style to a LabelFor element. I know it does not take any html attributes but I cannot get it to take the style when wrapped without squashing all of the letters together.

[image: LabelFor squished]

I've tried the following lines and have stopped just short of editing the template, but will if there is not an easier way.

```
<label>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.keyId)</label>
<div class="pure-form label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.keyId)</div>
```

EDIT: Yes sorry it is wrapped in pures "pure-form-aligned".

```
    <div class="pure-form pure-form-aligned">

    <fieldset>

        <div class="pure-control-group">
            <div class="pure-form ">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.keyId)</div>
```

Comment: Is this wrapped in a form that is using the pure-form class?

Answer (score 1):

What makes you think `LabelFor` cannot accept HTML attributes? It definitely can:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Foo, new { @class = "myclass" })
```

Comment: I had been reading old information. Before MVC 4 it did not accept html attributes. Thanks for the heads up anyways.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue was was with grid nesting. The partial was nested in a view and I had ended up with three sets of nested grids (including the grid in the layout view). Removing the grids from the partial fixed it.